# How do I check to make sure an array has been allocated before I delete it

Tags: c++, arrays

I am creating a character array based on the size of the file I read it. In the case that the file is not found, the array is not created. When I call my destructor, I get an error which I think is telling me that the pointer is invalid BECAUSE the file was not found. What I want to do is simply check to see if the class has correctly loaded in the file into the buffer. I could add a success flag and check it in the destructor, but I assume there is a better way.

In the class header:

```
uint32          m_fileSize;
char*           m_fileBuffer;
```

In the constructor:

```
m_fileSize = 0;
m_fileBuffer = 0;
```

In the initialize function:

```
std::ifstream file(filename.c_str(), std::ios::in|std::ios::binary|std::ios::ate);

if (file.is_open())
{
    m_fileSize = (int)file.tellg();
    m_fileBuffer = new char[m_fileSize];
    file.seekg (0, std::ios::beg);
    file.read (m_fileBuffer, m_fileSize);
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

In the destructor:

```
    if(m_fileBuffer)
    {
        delete [] m_fileBuffer;
    }
```

To recap, when file is present and loaded, it works great. When it's not there, I get an access violation reading the `if(m_fileBuffer)` line. I am trying to check to see if the array exists and then delete it if it does.

Comment: Use RAII so you don't have to worry about this in the first place.

Comment: what is the error exactly? looks like it should work fine.

Comment: The error points to the if(m_fileBuffer) line. Unhandled exception at 0x00087bbc in Loader.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xccccccf0.

Comment: @PladniusBrooks, what are you doing on the previous line? if() check shouldn't emit access violation, so maybe problem is in the previous statement, but debugger moves "execution position" further automatically.

Comment: @Steed the destructor for this class is being called from another destructor. Could that be an issue? This is an object inside another class.

Comment: Your problem lies in the code between the constructor and the destructor. You might have a double-delete (the `this` pointer is bad).

Answer (score 1):

Remember to initialize your array pointer to NULL. Otherwise the value is undefined and the check might not work.

Remember to set your pointer to NULL after you deleted the array. Otherwise the if check will pass again and you will get a segmentation fault.

You're may be getting a warning from the compiler. And if you had used `valgrind` you would surely get a warning about checking an unitialized value.

Comment: Sorry, i missed setting the pointer to 0 - I think it's bad practice. It's misleading.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (file.is_open())
{
    m_fileSize = (int)file.tellg();

    if(0 < m_fileSize)
        m_fileBuffer = new char[m_fileSize];
    .....
    .....
}
```

In the destructor:

```
if(m_fileSize && m_fileBuffer)
{
    delete [] m_fileBuffer;
}
```

Comment: Good catch, but `0 < m_fileSize`... People have been doing this a lot recently and I see such code much too often. It's unreadable!

Comment: The code never gets to the filesize part because the file isn't found. So the m_fileBuffer remains null.